# NestJs + TypeScript + Jest - TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I ran into an error when was trying to add some tests to my NestJs App.
There is auto generated test file named *app.controller.spec.ts* which is a unit test. When i try to run tests with the *yarn test* command it throws an Error stating:

> Test suite failed to run
> TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
>
> ```
>  at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/services/testing-logger.service.js:7:38)
>  at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js:9:34)
> ```

My tsconfig configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

yarn test command:
`"test": "jest"`

Content of the unit test file:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import {ConfigModule} from './config/config.module';

describe('AppController', () => {
  let appController: AppController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService],
    }).compile();

    appController = app.get<AppController>(AppController);
  });

  describe('root', () => {
    it('should return "pong"', () => {
      expect(appController.getHello()).toBe('pong');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What are you `@nestjs/` package versions? Can you add those to your question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Here they are:
"@nestjs/common": "6.7.2",
"@nestjs/core": "6.7.2",
"@nestjs/jwt": "6.1.1",
"@nestjs/mongoose": "6.1.2",
"@nestjs/passport": "6.1.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "6.7.2",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "6.2.0",
"jest": "24.9.0"

NodeJs version: v14.17.4

Comment: Furthermore, utils that i used to find circular dependencies (first, i thought it was causing the problem) say there's no circular dependencies in the project.

Comment: Oh wow, back on Nest v6. What about your dev deps for `@nestjs/` as well

Comment: "@nestjs/cli": "6.9.0",
"@nestjs/schematics": "6.7.0",
"@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.6"

I really appreciate your feedback, yet i suppose the question is not relevant for me anymore. As we had no time for searching for a solution, we decided just to write API tests with postman. We can still work around it, so it would help others who is facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `@nestjs/testing` on version 8, but you're using `@nestjs/common`, `@nestjs/core`, and many other `@nestjs/` packages down on version 6. These major versions should match each other. Either upgrade everything up to v8, or downgrade `@nestjs/testing` to v6 to match the common and core packages.